# Load Javascript file on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, localhost

My webpage creates a new script element and then loads the script from a localhost server. The problem is that the script cannot be loaded and shows PROTOCOL ERROR:

```
https://localhost:4200/script/test.js net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="./public/nps.style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script>
          j = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0],
          k = document.createElement('script');
          k.src = 'http://localhost:4200/script/test.js';
          j.parentNode.insertBefore(k,j);
        </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Testing</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then create a localhost server to listen it so the JavaScript file can be downloaded

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const { test } = require('./script/test.js');

const api = express();
api.use(cors({origin: '*'}));
api.use('/script', express.static('public'));

api.listen(4200, () => {
  console.log("Server listening");
})
```

test.js:
`alert("it works!");`

How can I solve this issue?

**Update:**

Initially I had the source of the new script element as `'https://localhost:4200/script/test.js'`, So I changed to http, a new error occurred:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/script/test.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just change 2 lines of your `index.js` code to solve it. Try with this code :

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
// const { test } = require('./script/test.js');

const api = express();
api.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));
api.use(express.static('public'));
api.use('/script', express.static('script'));

api.listen(4200, () => {
    console.log("Server listening");
});
```

And make sure your directory/file management looks like this :

[image: file management]

Comment: I’m just curious how this changes anything because he is getting a protocol error which means that he’s trying to hit HTTPS on the local machine

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered not using https? It looks like this could be your issue running locally.
The protocol error is the giveaway.